# htaccess restrict webpage file from URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My goals are to prevent users from figuring out what scripting language I am using for my website. The URL structure of my website is http://example.com/login/ which is http://example.com/?page=login.

The page parameter checks to see if the file exists. For an example *?page=login* will check if *login.php* file exists and includes it in the *index.php* file as the requested page to load. If the page doesn't exists then the *error.php* page will be its replacement, saying "page not found".

I want to Trigger the error page (add *?page=error* to the query) on theses conditions:

> **Condition 1:** The file extension is added to the requested URI.
>   Example: http://example.com/login.php and even the index.php file,
>   http://example.com/index.php
>
> **Condition 2:** The file doesn't exists. Example:
>   http://example.com/notinserver.php or
>   http://example.com/notinserver.whatever
>
> **Condition 3:** The file extensions are not *css, js, jpg, jpeg, gif, or
>   png* files (http://example.com/images/logo.jpg). To make it clear, the
>   URI must not have a period unless its an allowed extension, such
>   http://example.com/css/style.css
>
> **Condition 4**: When http://example.com/index/ is written. The webpage
>   doesn't need to include itself.

I couldn't get past condition 1 because the server throws me internal errors due to unlimited redirects on of default page, http://example.com/, or when *index.php* is written. Here's what I have so far:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/ ?page=$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.
RewriteRule . ?page=error [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#Condition 1:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.php$
#Condition 3:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ![\.jpg|\.gif|\.css|\.js]$
RewriteRule . ?page=error [L]
```